# decoding JSON data with backslash encoding

Tags: python, json

I have the following JSON data.

```
"[
    \"msgType\": \"0\",
    \"tid\": \"1\",
    \"data\": \"[
        {
            \\\"EventName\\\": \\\"TExceeded\\\",
            \\\"Severity\\\": \\\"warn\\\",
            \\\"Subject\\\": \\\"Exceeded\\\",
            \\\"Message\\\": \\\"tdetails: {
                \\\\\\\"Message\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"my page tooktoolong(2498ms: AT: 5ms,
                BT: 1263ms,
                CT: 1230ms),
                andexceededthresholdof5ms\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"Referrer\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"undefined\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"Session\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"None\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"ResponseTime\\\\\\\": 0,
                \\\\\\\"StatusCode\\\\\\\": 0,
                \\\\\\\"Links\\\\\\\": 215,
                \\\\\\\"Images\\\\\\\": 57,
                \\\\\\\"Forms\\\\\\\": 2,
                \\\\\\\"Platform\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Linuxx86_64\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"BrowserAppname\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Netscape\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"AppCodename\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Mozilla\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"CPUs\\\\\\\": 8,
                \\\\\\\"Language\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"en-GB\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"isEvent\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"true\\\\\\\",
                \\\\\\\"PageLatency\\\\\\\": 2498,
                \\\\\\\"Threshold\\\\\\\": 5,
                \\\\\\\"AT\\\\\\\": 5,
                \\\\\\\"BT\\\\\\\": 1263,
                \\\\\\\"CT\\\\\\\": 1230
            }\\\",
            \\\"EventTimestamp\\\": \\\"1432514783269\\\"
        }
    ]\",
    \"Timestamp\": \"1432514783269\",
    \"AppName\": \"undefined\",
    \"Group\": \"UndefinedGroup\"
]"
```

I want to make this JSON file into a single level of wrapping.i.e I want to remove the nested structure inside and copy that data over to the top level JSON structure. How can I do this?

If this strucutre is named json_data

I want to be able to access

```
json_data['Platform']
json_data[BrowserAppname']
json_data['Severity']
json_data['msgType']
```

Basically some kind of rudimentary normalization.What is the easiest way to do this using python

Comment: This cannot possible have been JSON serialized data.

Comment: @JamesMills: It looks like JSON-serialized data where for some insane reason the code recursively JSON-serialized every value in every object or array, before serializing the objects and arrays…

Comment: The obvious answer here is to fix the code that _generates_ this file, so it just calls `json.dumps` or `JSON.serialize` or whatever instead of recursively JSON-ifying every element before JSON-ifying it again. Can you not do that?

Comment: I agree; whoever or whatever created this data should be fixed.

Comment: @JamesMills: **Who**ever? Good point! :-)

Comment: That looks as if someone has recursively created strings from a nested structure, so the backslashes have doubled on each nesting level.

Answer (score 0):

A generally unsafe but probably okay in this case solution would be:

```
import json

d = json.loads(json_string.replace('\\', ''))
```

Comment: It is not a file. But a buffer containing JSON data.

Comment: Thanks @liv2hak. I took out the file handling code.

Comment: Sorry @abarnet, I'd accidentally edited out the backslash replacement, which is the actual unsafe part.

Comment: It's unsafe because it could very well change the meaning of the JSON without failing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened but this doesn't look like valid JSON.

1. You have some double-quotes escaped once, some twice, some three times etc.
2. You have key/value pairs inside of a list-like object `[]`
3. `tdetails` is missing a trailing quote

Even if you fix the above you still have your `data` list quoted as a multi-line string which is invalid.

It appears to be that this "JSON" was constructed by hand, by someone with no knowledge of JSON.

You can try "massaging" the data into JSON with the following:

```
import re
x = re.sub(r'\\+', '', js_str)
x = re.sub(r'\n', '', js_str)
x = '{' + js_str.strip()[1:-1] + '}'
```

Which would make the string almost json like, but you still need to fix point #3.